# How are the latency different when kernel-function called from CPU-host or by using dynamic parallelism from GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, latency

How are the latency different, and what approximate value of latency, when calling kernel-function  and synchronization - waiting for its completion:

- when the called from the GPU - from other kernel-function by using dynamic parallelism: `kernel_function<<<>>>>(); cudaDeviceSynchronize();`
- when called from CPU-host: `kernel_function<<<>>>>(); cudaDeviceSynchronize();`

Answer (score 2):

Latencies are not specified in the CUDA documentation, and can vary significantly based on the actual kernels you are running, and the actual parameter arrangement you are passing to the kernel, and the OS and driver configuration you are using.

You'll need to run your own tests to discover the latencies in your specific case.